# Errors in 3rd person view control demo

Tags: java, math, opengl, lwjgl

So, I'm trying to make a 3rd person view control demo. This demo will show of the ability to do the following:

1) rotate the camera around the "player."

2) move the player based off the direction you push the joystick and the direction of the camera.

3) show the correct angle of the billboarded player sprite based on the player angle, and the camera angle.

Right now 1, and 2 are working, but I can't figure out whats wrong with the displaying the proper enemy angle.

This is the relevant code I got so far:

```
private void updateLogic(int delta) {

        if (joystick != null) {
            joystick.poll();


            rjoyAngle += ((joystick.getRXAxisValue()/5) );
            rjoyAngle = ((rjoyAngle + 360) % 360);

            System.out.println("rangle = " + rjoyAngle);


            camPos.x = (float) (player.pos.x - (Math.sin(rjoyAngle) * camRadius));
            camPos.z = (float) (player.pos.z + (Math.cos(-rjoyAngle) * camRadius));

            camYaw = (float) ((Math.toDegrees(((Math.atan2(-(camPos.x - player.pos.x), -(camPos.z - player.pos.z)))))+ 360) % 360);
            System.out.println("Cam X: " + camPos.x + " Z: " + camPos.z + " yaw: " + camYaw);


            float pyaw = ((player.yaw + 360) % 360);
            float eyaw = ((camYaw + 360) % 360);
            dirYaw = (pyaw + eyaw) % 360;

            if(joystick.getXAxisValue() >= -0.5f && joystick.getXAxisValue() <= 0.5f &&  joystick.getYAxisValue() >= -0.5f &&  joystick.getYAxisValue() <= 0.5f){
                //deadzone?
            }

            else{
                player.yaw = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(joystick.getXAxisValue(), joystick.getYAxisValue()));
                pyaw = ((player.yaw + 360) % 360);
                eyaw = ((camYaw + 360) % 360);
                dirYaw = (pyaw + eyaw) % 360;
                Vector3f move = new Vector3f();
                move.x -= 3 * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dirYaw));
                move.z -= 3 * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(dirYaw));

                Vector3f.add(player.pos, move, player.pos);

            }

            pyaw = ((player.yaw + 360) % 360);
            eyaw = ((camYaw + 360) % 360);
            playerViewYaw = (dirYaw + eyaw) % 360;
        }

        player.update();
    }
```

And the draw and getSpriteNumber methods:

```
private void renderGL() {

        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
        loadIdentity(); // Reset The View


        floorTex.bind();
        GL11.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
        GL11.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS); // Start Drawing The Cube
            GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Set The Color To White
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);                                                                             GL11.glVertex3f(-fieldSize, -groundDepth, -fieldSize);  // Top left Of The Quad (bottom)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(fieldSize/floorTex.getTextureWidth(),0);                                          GL11.glVertex3f(fieldSize, -groundDepth, -fieldSize);   // Top right Of The Quad (bottom)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(fieldSize/floorTex.getTextureWidth(),fieldSize/floorTex.getTextureHeight());      GL11.glVertex3f(fieldSize, -groundDepth, fieldSize);  // Bottom right Of The Quad (bottom)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,fieldSize/floorTex.getTextureHeight());                                         GL11.glVertex3f(-fieldSize, -groundDepth, fieldSize);   // Bottom left Of The Quad (bottom)
        GL11.glEnd(); // Done Drawing The Quad

        int direction = getSpriteNum(playerViewYaw);

        drawBillBoardSprite(playerTex[0][direction],player.pos, 0, 1,1,1, 5, 10);   
    }


    public int getSpriteNum(float direction){
        direction = (float) Math.abs(Math.floor((direction + 22.5) / 45.0));

    //  direction = direction * 2;

        if (direction == 8) direction = 0;

        return (int)direction;
    }
```

That should be the only code you need to see, but I'll post all of it just to be safe, and I'll even give you guys a zip of the project.

Dream.java:

```
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import org.lwjgl.input.Controller;
import org.lwjgl.input.Controllers;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class Dream {

    String windowTitle = "Dream - By William Starkovich";
    public boolean closeRequested = false;

    Player player;
    Vector3f camPos;
    float camYaw;
    float camRadius;
    float rjoyAngle = 0;
    Controllers controllers ;
    Controller joystick;
    Texture playerTex[][];
    Texture floorTex;
    float dirYaw;
    float playerViewYaw;
    long lastFrameTime; // used to calculate delta
    float fieldSize = 500;
    float groundDepth = 5;

    public void run() {

        createWindow();
        getDelta(); // Initialise delta timer
        init();
        initGL();


        while (!closeRequested) {
            pollInput(getDelta());
            updateLogic(getDelta());
            renderGL();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);

        }

        cleanup();
    }


    public void init(){
        player = new Player(0,0,0);
        camRadius = 25;
        camYaw = 0;
        camPos = new Vector3f(0,0,-camRadius);
        playerTex = new Texture[1][8];

        try{

             floorTex = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("data/graphics/floor.png"));                 

             for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
                 for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                     playerTex[i][j] = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("data/graphics/player/enemy"+i+"-"+j+".png"));
                 }
             }

             controllers = new Controllers();
             Controllers.create();
               if (Controllers.getControllerCount() > 0) {
                   joystick = Controllers.getController(0);
                   joystick.setXAxisDeadZone(0.7f);
                   joystick.setYAxisDeadZone(0.7f);
                   joystick.setRXAxisDeadZone(0.7f);
                   joystick.setRYAxisDeadZone(0.7f);
                   System.out.println("Joystick has "+joystick.getButtonCount() +" buttons. Its name is "+joystick.getName());
               }
               else joystick = null;
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initGL() {

        /* OpenGL */
        int width = Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        int height = Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); // Reset The Current Viewport
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION); // Select The Projection Matrix
        GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Projection Matrix
        GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, ((float) width / (float) height), 0.1f, 600.0f); // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select The Modelview Matrix
        GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Modelview Matrix

        GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH); // Enables Smooth Shading
        GL11.glClearColor(0, 0.3f, 0.5f, 1f); // Black Background
        GL11.glClearDepth(1.0f); // Depth Buffer Setup
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enables Depth Testing
        GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL); // The Type Of Depth Test To Do
        GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST); // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        GL11.glAlphaFunc(GL11.GL_GREATER, 0.9f);
    }

    private void updateLogic(int delta) {

        if (joystick != null) {
            joystick.poll();


            rjoyAngle += ((joystick.getRXAxisValue()/5) );
            rjoyAngle = ((rjoyAngle + 360) % 360);

            System.out.println("rangle = " + rjoyAngle);


            camPos.x = (float) (player.pos.x - (Math.sin(rjoyAngle) * camRadius));
            camPos.z = (float) (player.pos.z + (Math.cos(-rjoyAngle) * camRadius));

            camYaw = (float) ((Math.toDegrees(((Math.atan2(-(camPos.x - player.pos.x), -(camPos.z - player.pos.z)))))+ 360) % 360);
            System.out.println("Cam X: " + camPos.x + " Z: " + camPos.z + " yaw: " + camYaw);


            float pyaw = ((player.yaw + 360) % 360);
            float eyaw = ((camYaw + 360) % 360);
            dirYaw = (pyaw + eyaw) % 360;

            if(joystick.getXAxisValue() >= -0.5f && joystick.getXAxisValue() <= 0.5f &&  joystick.getYAxisValue() >= -0.5f &&  joystick.getYAxisValue() <= 0.5f){
                //deadzone?
            }

            else{
                player.yaw = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(joystick.getXAxisValue(), joystick.getYAxisValue()));
                pyaw = ((player.yaw + 360) % 360);
                eyaw = ((camYaw + 360) % 360);
                dirYaw = (pyaw + eyaw) % 360;
                Vector3f move = new Vector3f();
                move.x -= 3 * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dirYaw));
                move.z -= 3 * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(dirYaw));

                Vector3f.add(player.pos, move, player.pos);

            }

            pyaw = ((player.yaw + 360) % 360);
            eyaw = ((camYaw + 360) % 360);
            playerViewYaw = (dirYaw + eyaw) % 360;
        }

        player.update();
    }


    private void loadIdentity(){
        /* OpenGL */
        int width = Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        int height = Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

        GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Modelview Matrix
        //roatate the yaw around the Y axis
        GL11.glRotatef(camYaw, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glTranslatef(camPos.x, -3, camPos.z);
    }

    private void renderGL() {

        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
        loadIdentity(); // Reset The View


        floorTex.bind();
        GL11.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
        GL11.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS); // Start Drawing The Cube
            GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Set The Color To White
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);                                                                             GL11.glVertex3f(-fieldSize, -groundDepth, -fieldSize);  // Top left Of The Quad (bottom)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(fieldSize/floorTex.getTextureWidth(),0);                                          GL11.glVertex3f(fieldSize, -groundDepth, -fieldSize);   // Top right Of The Quad (bottom)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(fieldSize/floorTex.getTextureWidth(),fieldSize/floorTex.getTextureHeight());      GL11.glVertex3f(fieldSize, -groundDepth, fieldSize);  // Bottom right Of The Quad (bottom)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,fieldSize/floorTex.getTextureHeight());                                         GL11.glVertex3f(-fieldSize, -groundDepth, fieldSize);   // Bottom left Of The Quad (bottom)
        GL11.glEnd(); // Done Drawing The Quad

        int direction = getSpriteNum(playerViewYaw);

        drawBillBoardSprite(playerTex[0][direction],player.pos, 0, 1,1,1, 5, 10);   
    }


    public int getSpriteNum(float direction){
        direction = (float) Math.abs(Math.floor((direction + 22.5) / 45.0));

    //  direction = direction * 2;

        if (direction == 8) direction = 0;

        return (int)direction;
    }

    public void drawBillBoardSprite(Texture texture, Vector3f sprPos, float y, float r, float g, float b, float sprWidth, float sprHeight){
         // store the current model matrix
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glColor3f(r,g,b);
            GL11.glTranslatef(-sprPos.x, y, -sprPos.z);
            // bind to the appropriate texture for this sprite
            texture.bind();

            FloatBuffer modelview = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

            // get the current modelview matrix
            GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);

            // Note that a row in the C convention is a column 
            // in OpenGL convention (see the red book, pg.106 in version 1.2)
            // right vector is [1,0,0]  (1st column)
            // lookAt vector is [0,0,1] (3d column)
            // leave the up vector unchanged (2nd column)
            // notice the increment in i in the first cycle (i+=2)
            for(int i=0; i<3; i+=2 ) 
                for(int j=0; j<3; j++ ) {
                    if ( i==j )
                        modelview.put(i*4+j, 1.0f);
                    else
                        modelview.put(i*4+j, 0.0f);
                }

            // set the modelview matrix
            GL11.glLoadMatrix(modelview);

            // draw a quad textured to match the sprite
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);                                     GL11.glVertex3f((float) - (sprWidth/2),(float) (sprHeight/2), 0);    // Top left Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), 0);                   GL11.glVertex3f((float) + (sprWidth/2),(float) (sprHeight/2), 0);  // Top right Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight()); GL11.glVertex3f((float) + (sprWidth/2),(float) -(sprHeight/2), 0);   // Bottom right Of The Quad (Left)
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, texture.getHeight());                  GL11.glVertex3f((float) - (sprWidth/2),(float) -(sprHeight/2), 0);   // Bottom left Of The Quad (Left)
            GL11.glEnd();

        // restore the model view matrix to prevent contamination
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }

    /**
     * Poll Input
     */
    public void pollInput(float delta) {    

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_F12)){
            closeRequested = true;
        }

        if (Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            closeRequested = true;
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Calculate how many milliseconds have passed 
     * since last frame.
     * 
     * @return milliseconds passed since last frame 
     */
    public int getDelta() {
        long time = (Sys.getTime() * 1000) / Sys.getTimerResolution();
        int delta = (int) (time - lastFrameTime);
        lastFrameTime = time;

        return delta;
    }


    private void createWindow() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
            Display.setFullscreen(true);
            Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
            Display.setTitle(windowTitle);
            Display.create();

            //hide the mouse
            Mouse.setGrabbed(true);
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            Sys.alert("Error", "Initialization failed!\n\n" + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy and clean up resources
     */
    private void cleanup() {
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dream dream = new Dream();
        dream.run();
    }
}
```

Player.java:

```
import java.util.Vector;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;


public class Player {
    float mouseSensitivity = 0.05f;
    float movementSpeed = 0.04f; //move 10 units per second

    Vector3f pos;
    float yaw = 0;
    float pitch = 0;
    float maxPitch = 90;

    float width = 1;
    float height = 1;

    int inFieldType = 0;


    public Player(float sx, float sz, float sa){
        pos = new Vector3f(sx,0,sz);
        yaw = sa;
    }

    public void update(){

    }
}
```

And here is the demo project (in Eclipse):
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28109593/Dream.zip

Comment: I can't figure out what's wrong either, and am not terribly inclined to pore through a code dump to guess.  What behavior are you expecting?  What is happening instead?

Comment: I'm expecting that I can rotate the camera to view all 8 player angles, and then from where the camera is I can push up on the joystick to make him go the direction the camera is facing and turn the sprite to it's back facing the camera. Right now it does all that except turning the sprite to it's back facing the camera.

Comment: Have you actually written code to try and make the sprite turn to face its back to the camera? If so, that is more relevant than whatever else you've posted. Also your `update()` method in the `Player` class is empty, what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem (updateLogic() lines 147/157 and 168):

```
dirYaw = (pyaw + eyaw) % 360;
...
playerViewYaw = (dirYaw + eyaw) % 360;
```

You're trying to calculate the direction the player is viewed from, but you're performing the same compensation twice.

(Also, I think you would want to **subtract** the camera yaw from the player yaw to get the angle the camera is viewing the player from).